# Is it possible to filter MongoDB query results?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am developing a simple web application that fetches data from MongoDB.

What I need to do, is to show data matching the query on the webpage. Let's say the user has to choose a

- programming language **[Java, C#, Python]**
- project creation time **[all, max week ago, max month ago]**
- implemented algorithm **[heapsort, quicksort, mergesort]**

Now, my MongoDB collection contains all types of object, some of which are not necessarily an algorithm at all (this is unavoidable, unfortunately).

Because of this fact, I have a specific query that finds all the documents which are eligible to further processing.

```
FindIterable<Document> docs = collection.find(Filters.ex(programmingLanguage));
```

And here comes my final question:

**When I already have a FindIterable object, can I filter it so that only specific documents from previously selected documents will be chosen?**

For example, I need a line of code, that will give me only documents created no longer than a month ago which are written in Java, given **docs** object.

Desirably I would implement it like this:

create function that applies additional filter on a FindIterable object

```
public static FindIterable<Document> applyLastMonth(FindIterable<Document> docs) {
    return docs.<magicfunction>(Filters.gte("date", dateMonthAgo()))
}
```

and apply it to wherever it is needed. Is it possible?

My problem is much more complex, so please do not solve the example given above, I just want to be able to filter results returned by other query, so that I don't look at dozens of cases in my code. Unfortunately I found out that docs.filter(...) does not work for me, as it replaces the old query with the new one.

Comment: Voting to close this as this is trying to circumvent the requirement for specific programming questions. And of course you can filter: Adjust your data model and you queries accordingly. Please rephrase your question, and include a data model and a working example. You want us to solve your problem, so please make it as easy as you can. Proper effort shown increases the motivation for helping you, btw.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot include original data model as this would be inconsistent with my company's policy. I'd gladly share more if it was possible. I just want to know if there is a way to query a query, if you get what I mean. I found one workaround, however it won't work in all the cases, so I wanted to ask people with experience in using Mongo java driver.

Comment: No, that's not possible. A cursor can't be queried. Either use aggregations or query correctly right away.

Comment: Right, that's an answer I was looking for, thanks! I just have to find other way to achieve my goals.

Comment: Well, model your data according to the questions you are going to ask. That's the NoSQL way.

Comment: I would, however it is not completely feasible, because the database content is not solely dependent on me. Right now I added the query with dynamic parameter calculated by another function like this:
collection.find(Filters.gte("myfield", getMyQueryValue(parameter)));
 and it seems to work. Thanks for your input and help anyways!